# How to read Server Certificate using curl in C/C++

Tags: curl, certificate, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I have a requirement where I need to read the contents of the certificate that the server (say gmail.com) sends to me. I am using Curl in C.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

libcurl provides **curl_easy_getinfo()** function with that can be used with **CURLINFO_CERTINFO** argument to read information about certificates returned by the HTTPS server. See [this page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) for more information about the mentioned function.

[This page](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/certinfo.html) shows a simple example (**certificate.c** file) how to print information about certificates.

If you need to work with content of the certificate(s), you probably need to extract the content between "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and "-----END CERTIFICATE-----" markers.